# EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude: ArgumentNotNull does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I just upgraded to EF6 from EF5 and I encounter this error in a custom T4 that connects to the DB using a DbContext from a different assembly.

> File: EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude
>
> Compiling transformation: The name 'ArgumentNotNull' does not exist in the current context

What I've done is replacing `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` with `EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude`, which solved another error about `DbSet` and `DbContext` not being found.

The T4 is very simple, like this one:

```cs
using(var context = new EntityContext)
    return context.Entities.Where(x => 1==1);
```

Except for the EF include I only reference my own assemblies. The freshly-added Context is generating just fine (in another project).

What on earth could be wrong?

Comment: Which visual studio are you using ?

Comment: 2017 community with EF6 component installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude** reference some static functions that are defined in the main template.tt so you need to have them in your template too.

Example:
Entity.tt defines **ArgumentNotNull**(T arg, string name) which is used in the EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude (it's not the way we are used to have)

See the bottom of generated template from EF6 designer to see this missing functions

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is moving almost all the code to a .cs file and then use that file in the T4 template. Then remove the EF ttinclude from the T4 template.

Works and is easy better praxis to follow.